# Problem with cell alignment in table with multicolumn

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am trying to migrate my table draft from Word to LaTeX.

[image: Business Model Canvas]

The following LaTeX code has problems with the cell alignment of "Revenue Streams".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Key Partnerships} & Key Activities & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Value Proposition}} & Customer Relationships & \multirow{2}{*}{Customer Segments} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
                                  & Key Resources  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                   & Channels               &                                    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Cost Structure}                                            & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Revenue Streams}                                                     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled LaTeX code]

Suggestions how to create the correct cell alignment?

Comment: `\multicolumn{3}{|p{5cm}|}{Cost Structure}` Untested, because no testable document.

Comment: Why the msword tag?

Comment: Will this be all the text within the table? Or is there other text coming later?

Comment: Why not simply use the table created in Word (using a matching font?) Seems simpler.

Comment: I like it more when it's completely in LaTeX, that was my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have equal widths cells, the simplest solution is to stack two `tabularx` environments of the same total width and adjust the vertical spacing between both. Anyway, your table can't fit the margins in normal size.

So I propose two variants, both with the `\small` font size. One has all cells one-lined, at the cost of enlarging the printable area for the table. This is done with the `changepage` package, and its `adjustwidth` environment. The other fits the margins, at the cost of some line breaks, and a redefinition of the `X` column type  for the vertical alignment of cells contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx, caption, makecell}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.2cm}{-1.2cm}
\centering\small\captionsetup{skip=6pt, font=small}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{6}{X|}}
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Key Partnerships} & Key Activities & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Value Proposition}} & Customer Relationships & \multirow{2}{*}{Customer Segments} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
 & Key Resources & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & Channels & \\ \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{Cost Structure} & \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{Revenue Streams} \\ \hline
 \end{tabularx}\\[-0.5\extrarowheight]%\
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{2}{X|}}
Cost Structure & Revenue Streams \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\centering\small\captionsetup{skip=6pt, font=small}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{6}{X|}}
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Key Partnerships} & Key Activities & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Value Proposition}} & Customer \newline Relationships & \multirow{2}{*}{Customer Segments} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
 & Key Resources & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & Channels & \\ \hline
 \end{tabularx} \\ [-0.5\extrarowheight]%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{2}{X|}}
Cost Structure & Revenue Streams \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{6}{L|}}
    \hline
\multirow{4}{=}{Key Partnerships}  & Key Activities
    & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X|}{Value Proposition}
        & Customer Relationships & \multirow{4}{=}{Customer Segments}   \\
    \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
        & Key Resources
            & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X|}{}
                & \multirow{2}{=}{Channels}  &                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep}X|}{Cost Structure}
    & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep}X|}{Revenue Streams}     \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```